# Getting NameError even though variable is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find all the numbers that divide all the element of `b` evenly.

This is my code:

```
a = [2, 4]
b = [16, 32, 96]
maxOfb = max(b)
factorOfb = []
for i in range(1, int(maxOfb/2)):
    if all(j % i == 0 for j in b):
        factorOfb.append(j)
print(factorOfb)
```

when I'm executing it, it's giving this error:

```
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `factorOfb.append(i)`? `j` is not exposed outside of the generator expression... Anyway `j` is the ***number***, `i` are the ***factors***

Answer (score 0):

Note that the error is caused by the line:

```py
factorOfb.append(j)
```

and not by  `if all(j % i == 0 for j in b)`.

This is because `j` in the [local scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) of the generator. So once the list is generated, `j` will also not be available to the other parts of the program until `j` is explicitly defined as a [global variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20global,global%20environment%20or%20global%20state.) (which I dont know if it's possible to do inside a generator expression)

As `@Tomerikoo` said, the element that you want to append is `i` and not `j`. You should be able to append `i` though since it is in the scope of the function.

**Suggestion:** To solve the problem you could also find the [GCD( or HCF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20greatest%20common,is%204%2C%20that%20is%2C%20.) and then just factorise the GCD to get your answer.

However, Since you have asked, If you really want to append `j` you can try the following:

```py
a = [2, 4]
b = [16, 32, 96]
maxOfb = max(b)
ls = []
for i in range(1, int(maxOfb/2)):
    if all([j % i == 0 or ls.append(j) for j in b]):
        pass

print(ls)
```

Explantion : `ls.append()` function returns `NoneType` object. The boolean of a `NoneType` object is `False`. So using the `or` operator and then calling the `append()` function will at the same time append the element to the list and also will not deviate from the required result.

Comment: `ls.extend(filter(lambda j: j % i == 0, b))` would be much cleaner.

Comment: @chepner +1 . Thats sick !